# Why I can't add custom markup to user_profile

Tags: drupal

I want to add some markup to user profile page

in template.php

```
function athens_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables) {
 $markup = 'hello';

 $variables['elements']['social'] = array(
 '#weight' => 0,
 '#markup' => '<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="author-social">' . $markup  . '</div>',
);
```

but noting change :(

Comment: Use hook for user profile instead

Answer (score 0):

The `user-profile.tpl.php` template uses the `$user_profile` for output rendering. You should add your custom markup field to the `user_profile` key.

```
function athens_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables) 
{
    $markup = 'hello';

    $variables['user_profile']['social'] = array(
        '#weight' => 0,
        '#markup' => '<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="author-social">' . $markup  . '</div>',
    );
}
```